# Save a figure to file with specific resolution

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, resolution

In an old version of my code, I used to do a `hardcopy()` with a given resolution, ie:

```
frame = hardcopy(figHandle, ['-d' renderer], ['-r' num2str(round(pixelsperinch))]);
```

For reference, `hardcopy` saves a figure window to file.

Then I would typically perform:

```
ZZ = rgb2gray(frame) < 255/2;
se = strel('disk',diskSize);
ZZ2 = imdilate(ZZ,se); %perform dilation.
Surface = bwarea(ZZ2); %get estimated surface (in pixels)
```

This worked until I switched to Matlab 2017, in which the `hardcopy()` function is deprecated and we are left with the `print()` function instead.

I am unable to extract the data from figure handler at a specific resolution using `print`. I've tried many things, including:

```
frame = print(figHandle, '-opengl', strcat('-r',num2str(round(pixelsperinch))));
```

But it doesn't work. How can I overcome this?

**EDIT**

I don't want to 'save' nor create a figure file, my aim is to extract the data from the figure in order to mesure a surface after a dilation process.  I just want to keep this information and since 'im processing a LOT of different trajectories (total is approx. 1e7 trajectories), i don't want to save each file to disk (this is costly, time execution speaking). I'm running this code on a remote server (without a graphic card).

The issue I'm struggling with is: `"One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "varargout"."`

`getframe()` does not allow for setting a specific resolution (it uses current resolution instead as far as I know)

**EDIT2**
Ok, figured out how to do, you need to pass the '-RGBImage' argument like this:

```
frame = print(figHandle, ['-' renderer], ['-r' num2str(round(pixelsperinch))], '-RGBImage');
```

it also accept custom resolution and renderer as specified in the documentation.

Comment: Take a look at the excellent [export_fig()](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) function!

Comment: What version of MATLAB were you using before? As of 2015b the `hardcopy` documentation included the warning "Do NOT use this function directly. Use PRINT instead" - these warnings are in place for a reason... using the `-r0` flag should use the current resolution.

Comment: @Zep I don't want to create a figure file, but recover the data from figure and use it for estimating a surface. Will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Wolfie I used Matlab 2011b for a while. I don't want to use the current resolution because I'm running this on a server with no graphic card and for comparison purpose I need a a fixed resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must specify formattype too (-dtiff in my case). I've tried this in Matlab 2016b with no problem:

```
print(figHandle,'-dtiff', '-opengl', '-r600', 'nameofmyfig');
```

**EDIT:** 
If you need the CData just find the handle of the corresponding axes and get its CData

```
f = findobj('Tag','mytag')
```

Then depending on your matlab version use:

```
mycdata = get(f,'CData');
```

or directly

```
mycdta = f.CData;
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can set the tag of your image programatically and then do what I said previously:

```
a = imshow('peppers.png');
set(a,'Tag','mytag');
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but it doesn't work for me. 
I want to gather the data of the figHandle for estimating the surface, will edit my question.

Comment: can you specify what is the "data" you want to extract from the figHandle? do you mean the 'CData' of the image?

Comment: Yes cdata should suffice since rgb2gray() takes a 3D array in argument. I think hardcopy() also returned cdata but it's hard to tell since I cannot use it anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. But regarding your edit and using findobj() how could I get the CData from the figure at a defined resolution? the Print() call dump a file on the disk, then I need to call imshow() set the tag and get the cdata. This is much more complicated (and time consuming, execution speaking) than the previous hardcopy() method. Hardcopy() could perform this on the fly.

Comment: when you call imshow(), the variable 'a' contains the cdata structure of the image. but it's still so much slow to write and read from he disk....

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your problem. If you are plotting a matrix/image in your figure, and you want to change its resolution to keep it, somewhere the hardcopy() function must be resizing the matrix/image. That should not be faster than resizing the data yourself (e.g. using imresize). Why don't you put the exact code where you actually plot the data into your figure?

Comment: Figured out how to do it. You need to put the '-RGBImage' argument to the Print function in order to retrieve cdata from the figure. Did not spotted that. Regarding your question, my point was that writing and reading each file from the disk is really slow. That's why I wanted to get cdata directly from the figure Handler. Thanks!